# All My activities show for other person name

Tags: contacts, activities

I registered someone in CiviCRM and now after doing some activities I saw all my activities for her name and I think both of us link together how can I unlink without losing any information?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: All my action record by her name. for example when I create a new email and send it to the group in the created by and sent by  I see her name not my own user name.

Answer (score 1):

**The Problem**

When you are logged in to CiviCRM, ALL public-facing pages (event registration, contributions, etc.) will assume that you're the logged-in person.  There's a warning on the page with a link to let you register/contribute as someone else (see screenshot below).

**Preventing this**

All registrations/contributions should be added via the back-office screens, not public screens.  If you need a public screen, use the link circled below.

Furthermore, the excellent [No Overwrite](https://civicrm.org/extensions/no-overwrite) extension should be installed wherever a) it's possible that someone might overwrite another record, and b) you don't need to permit visitors to overwrite their name during registration/contribution.

**Fixing After it's Happened**

This must be fixed by hand.

- Figure out all the information on the shared contact that belongs to the new person.  You can figure this out by looking at the public-facing page.  Any fields on that page are most likely overwritten.
- Put the fields (name, etc.) back the way they were before the bad transaction.  If you're not sure, you may want to load a backup of your database on to a test server to compare side-by-side.
- Create a new record (if necessary) for the new contact and populate it with their info.
- Additionally, this record will have one or more contribution/membership/participant/activity records associated with the transaction.
- If you **have** back-end access to the database, change the contribution/membership/participant/activity records so the `contact_id` is changed to the new contact.
- If you **don't have** back-end access, you'll need to delete the transaction and do it again (don't forget to refund the money before charging again, if applicable).
- If the contact was supposed to be added to a group based on a profile in the page, don't forget to add them (and potentially remove it from the mixed contact).
  [image]